# staringatlights:fast-render with Meteor v2.3+?

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to update my Meteor app to v2.3 (on my way to version 2.6...).

I'm getting the following error:

```
While selecting package versions:
error: Conflict: Constraint accounts-base@1.4.2 is not satisfied by accounts-base 2.0.1.
Constraints on package "accounts-base":
* accounts-base@~2.0.0 <- top level
* accounts-base@2.0.0 <- accounts-password 2.0.1
* accounts-base@2.0.0 <- service-configuration 1.1.0 <- accounts-base 2.0.1 <- accounts-password 2.0.1
* accounts-base@2.0.0 <- accounts-ui 1.4.0
* accounts-base@2.0.0 <- accounts-ui-unstyled 1.5.0 <- accounts-ui 1.4.0
* accounts-base@1.4.2 <- staringatlights:fast-render 3.3.0
* accounts-base@1.9.0 || 2.0.0 <- alanning:roles 1.3.0`
```

It seems that staringatlights:fast-render has a dependency on accounts-base v1.4.2 but Meteor v2.3 wants to upgrade that to v2.0.1.

fast-render is already on its latest version 3.3.0 so there is no upgrade path available there. Does anyone have any suggestions other than just dropping fast-render altogether?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that my code doesn't actually reference FastRender at all so it was safe to comment out.

However, it seems that the [package found a new owner in in March 21](https://github.com/Meteor-Community-Packages/organization/issues/53) and has been forked as [meteor-fast-render](https://github.com/Meteor-Community-Packages/meteor-fast-render).